# Is object slicing by assigning through a base reference well-defined?

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, language-lawyer, object-slicing

Is the object slicing that occurs when assigning a derived object through a base class reference (without a virtual `operator=`) a well-defined operation? I.e., is it guaranteed by the standard to leave the derived parts of the object untouched?

In many questions regarding object slicing here and elsewhere, an example like the following is given:

```
struct Base{
    int x;
    Base(int xx) :x(xx) {}
    virtual void print() const {std::cout << "Base("<<x<<")\n";}
};

struct Derived : Base{
    int y;
    Derived(int xx, int yy ) :Base(xx),y(yy){}
    void print() const {std::cout << "Derived("<<x<<","<<y<<")\n";}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d1{1,2};
    Derived d2{3,4};

    Base& br = d1;
    br = d2;     // assign a Derived through a Base&

    br.print();  // prints Derived(3,2)
}
```

The example is intended to show that when assigning through a `Base&` it only assigns the `Base` class members and leaves the members in `Derived` untouched.

Building the above example with `-fsanitize=undefined` does not complain, and it produces the expected output on all systems I've run it.

The question is, is this guaranteed by the standard? In my understanding it is, as `Base::operator=` cannot write outside the `Base` part of the object, and the `Derived` part of the object (here `int y`) cannot have any overlap with the `Base` part.

Is there some corner case I am missing? (There are of course many ways having an inconsistent object can lead to undefined behaviour, but my question is limited to what happens during the assignment operation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Base& br = d1;
```

This creates a reference to a `Base` object. This will now be referencing a `Base` object that's just as well-formed as any other `Base` object (in a well-formed C++ program). In all respects, the referenced `Base` object is identical to all other `Base` objects that may or may not exist. This object can be assigned to just like any other `Base` object can be assigned to, and the exact same thing will happen to this object as to any other `Base` object that gets assigned to. The End.

Objects that are base objects of other objects are not any different than objects that are not, when viewed through the prism of those objects alone. They are well-formed objects of their own, and are just like any other `Base` object (ignoring things like virtual methods here). This is a fundamental concept in C++.

It would be rather inconvenient if assigning to a Base object suddenly "writes" somewhere else. It would be rather difficult to accomplish anything in C++, in that case. Of course, it goes without saying that one can always overload `operator=`, and then the sky's the limit. But from a practical point, as long as the `=` operator works the way it's expected to work, assigning to a `Base` object won't do anything to anything that's not a part of that `Base` object.

Answer (score 1):

> Is object slicing by assigning through a base reference well-defined?

Yes. Slicing is well defined operation.

> is it guaranteed by the standard to leave the derived parts of the object untouched?

The implicitly generated assignment operator of the base won't touch derived parts. A custom one could do so, although such design is uncommon.